# SQLServer CAST and divide 2 decimal numbers, followed by multiplication gives too many decimal places

Tags: sql

I'm working in SQL Server 2008.  I have an alias column that I'm creating via the following formula:

```
col1 / col2 * some_number
```

col1 and col2 are nvarchars in my table, but they're really integers.  some_number is an integer.  If I blindly do col1 / col2, I will get 0 for most.  So, I need to cast them as decimals.  I want there to be a maximum of 2 decimal places after the decimal point.  Here is what I have currently:

```
CAST(col1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / CAST(col2 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * 100
```

However, this returns far more decimal places than just 2.  How do I fix my code to return just 2 decimal places?

Comment: CAST(CAST(col1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / CAST(col2 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(10,2))

Comment: I'd consider pulling this sort of maths out into a function - it keeps your select clean, is more testable and will be helpful if you need to repeat it in the future

Comment: just take care to division by zero.

Comment: @Liath I would agree if this operation is being done frequently in other places I would have it in a function as well. But if its one off  I would not care to write a function for it.

Comment: Or you can do `ROUND(CAST(col1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / CAST(col2 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * 100, 2)` to return just 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190476.aspx) the scale of the result is given by:

> s2 = max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)

*where p2 represents the precision of the numerator and s2 represents scale of the denominator*

So when dividing one DECIMAL(10, 2) by another you can substitute in values:

```
s2 = max(6, 2 + 10 + 1) = 13
```

Which is corroborated with a simple example:

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(10,2))

= 1.0000000000000 -- 13 decimal points
```

You need to use another cast on your result to reduce the scale:

```
SELECT  CAST(CAST(col1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / CAST(col2 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * 100  AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
```

I'd also suggest if the data type of you column is nvarchar, "but they're really integers" that you just bite the bullet and alter the column data type.